# Get Value of php stdclass object value

Tags: php, object, stdclass

just tried several $result->key ($customer->transaction->status) but was not successful. i need the "status" value of this object in php. tried some combinations of array shift, ->object ->["status"] etc.

```
 object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
     ["customer"]=>
     object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
         ["link"]=>
         object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
             ["url"]=>
             string(78) "https://demo1.com"
             ["rel"]=>
             string(8) "customer"
             ["method"]=>
             string(3) "GET"
         }
     }
     ["transaction"]=>
     object(stdClass)#5 (9) {
         ["merchantRefId"]=>
         string(19) "46532156465456"
         ["amount"]=>
         int(200)
         ["currency"]=>
         string(3) "EUR"
         ["id"]=>
         string(15) "646544564564"
         ["transactionType"]=>
         string(27) "Transfer"
         ["createDate"]=>
         string(19) "2016-01-26 08:33:09"
         ["updateDate"]=>
         string(19) "2016-01-26 08:33:09"
         ["status"]=>
         string(8) "accepted"
         ["fees"]=>
         array(1) {
             [0]=>
             object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
                 ["feeType"]=>
                 string(11) "service_fee"
                 ["feeAmount"]=>
                 int(119)
                 ["feeCurrency"]=>
                 string(3) "EUR"
             }
         }
     }
     ["links"]=>
     array(1) {
         [0]=>
         object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
             ["url"]=>
             string(78) "https://demo.com"
             ["rel"]=>
             string(4) "self"
             ["method"]=>
             string(3) "GET"
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($customer->transaction);`?

Comment: thx 4 help, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide the code that creates your object, I've created JSON string and converted it to object, which gives similar `var_dump` result to yours.

```
<?php
    $jsonStr = '{
    "customer": {
        "link": {
            "url": "https://demo1.com",
            "rel": "customer",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    },
    "transaction": {
        "merchantRefId": "46532156465456",
        "amount": 200,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "id": "646544564564",
        "transactionType": "Transfer",
        "createDate": "2016-01-26 08:33:09",
        "updateDate": "2016-01-26 08:33:09",
        "status": "accepted",
        "fees": [
            {
              "feeType": "service_fee",
              "feeAmount": 119,
              "feeCurrency": "EUR"
            }
        ]
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "url": "https://demo.com",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}';

$stdObj = json_decode($jsonStr);        
var_dump($stdObj);        
var_dump($stdObj->transaction->status);
```

I am able, and you should be too, to simply get `status` with simple:

```
$customer->transaction->status
```